# find tags with particular criteria with object variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have copied the html contents of a div to a variable in javascript. Now i want to put the value of title attribute to the content of the TD tags whichever has the class as popup. So i created the following code. But it didn't help..

```
var tmpDiv = document.createElement("div");
tmpDiv.setAttribute("style","display:none");
$(tmpDiv).html($('#'+divid+" .scrollTableContainer").html());

$(tmpDiv+ 'td .popup').each(function(index,value) {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: hey man where is the `var divid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(tmpDiv).find('td.popup').each(function(index,value) {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

In your code tempDiv is javascript object so tempDiv+'td.popup' is not allowed.
Secondly if you need to find td with class popup remove space between td and .popup

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate a DOM object and a string to create a selector. You can't concatenate a string and an object

Would make more sense to use jQuery for all of your code

```
var tmpDiv=$('<div>').hide().html($('#'+divid+" .scrollTableContainer").html());

tmpDiv.find('td.popup').each(function(index,value) {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('title'));
});
```